# pactl do not found all my output audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have one build-in, one screen (NDMI1) and one projector (HDMI2) for audio output.
All are selectable in Ubuntu's graphics settings (22.04) and work perfectly.

[image]

But pactl do not detect them all:
When HDMI1 is selected HDMI2 is not visible anymore:

```
zorro@ubuntu:~$ pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

And when HDMI2 is selected HDMI1 is not visible anymore:

```
zorro@ubuntu:~$ pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

Both HDMIs are connected via the motherboard and this problem didn't exist before, I guess it may be caused by a recent Ubuntu/NVDIA update.

I need pactl to run my script on every boot to restore the default audio output...

System are up to date.
`pacmd list-cards` also show only two devices.